# How to properly exclude spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I tested the code below in STS. When the POM is empty, I get

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

This is correct. However, when I add a dependency of my other project without spring framework, I can get the class `org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`. This is even when I put an exclusion of the  spring framework in POM. It is very strange.

My question is that, when I put another project that is not related spring, why can I still get the spring context class? How should I exclude spring?

```java
public class CustomerClassloader extends ClassLoader {
    public void findTheClass() {
         try {
            Class result = findSystemClass(
              "org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext");
            System.out.println("result=" + result);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerClassloader loader = new CustomerClassloader();
        loader.findTheClass();
    }
}
```

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <artifactId>iotex-test</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.iotex.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>iotex-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../iotex-cloud/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <name>iotex-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.iotex.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>iotex-security-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.iotex.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>iotex-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>iotex-cloud</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- 指定Maven仓库 -->
    <repositories>
       <repository>
            <id>iotex</id>
            <name>nexus Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://localhost:7777/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository> 

    </repositories>


  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>iotex</id>
        <name>iotex-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:7777/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>iotex</id>
        <name>iotex-releases</name>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:7777/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
     <!--
    <site>
        <id>module-site</id>
        <name>openEjb-sit</name>
        <url>file://D:/OpenEjb/apache-openejb-4.5.2/lib/</url>
    </site>
    -->
   </distributionManagement>

  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- Logging -->

        <logback.version>1.1.1</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
   </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

     </dependencies>    
    </dependencyManagement>


    <modules>
        <module>../iotex-test</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: You have a parent pom too, that would be needed to analyze the dependency chain. Please share it.

Comment: In your dev environment Try adding the jar containing the class to the lib directory where all the runtime dependencies are added and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: finally , I add spring framework jars in the java build path of the project , and adjust the jars to the top order in the tag of Order and Export to resovle the issure 
,which might cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.clearCache()V 
but the real problem is not be resovled.